# socket.io how to read client certificate

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Can socket.io (on the server) read the SSL certificate from the client if the connection is done by a browser?
I have an html-page that initiate a long polling to a node server.
When the requet from the client comes to a node-app, node.js is able to read the client certificate with this code:

```
request.connection.getPeerCertificate()
```

However, Im trying to use sockets instead of longpolling.

In the socket-function on node-app I have this:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
```

However, inside this function I cannot use

```
request.connection.getPeerCertificate()
```

as there is not any "request" object here. What is coming in is the socket from the cient. I have outputted in the console all the content of the socket but I cannot see any field that correspond to

```
request.connection.getPeerCertificate()
```

Is there a way to "force" the socket on the client to also include the certificate/key when connecting to the server?

I have found a few resources about this issue. For example [here](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/issues/754).

Most of the comments seem to tell about socket.io not beeing able to read the certificate on the connected client.
The first post looks llike a work around. But I dont really understand how to implement that. Tjhere is no "io.Manager" in socket.io-source code.
If I output "io.Manager" to the console I then get an "undefined"

Comment: You can try to force the certification check by using `https`. Or, You can use `secure` option while connect `var socket = io.connect('https://localhost', {secure: true});` This forces the client certification check

Comment: I was already using https. I also added the secure:true flag. But it didnt help.

Answer (score 1):

`socket.client.request.client.getPeerCertificate()` seems to get you the certificate (I know !!)
Also if you've set https agent's `rejectUnauthorized` option to false, you can check `authorized` property from here to see if client is authorized based on given CA or not.